# Angular Post method does not redirect to the liqpay payment page

Tags: angular, forms, payment

The problem with this code is that it does not redirect to the liqpay payment page, although in the Postman when I use this post method with given url and body fields it works well

```
<div class="popup" *ngIf="order">
    <div class="popup-content">
        <app-purchase-summary [order]="order"></app-purchase-summary>
        <div>
            <form method="POST" action="https://www.liqpay.ua/api/3/checkout" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <input  name="data" value="{{data}}" />
                <input  name="signature" value="{{signature}}" />
                <input type="image" src="//static.liqpay.ua/buttons/p1ru.radius.png" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```